# How to deploy a website and webservice in AWS using same domain name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

We have to deploy Restful Webservice(API services) and static pages in the AWS environment.
Currently, our Webservice is hosted in EC2 instance with one ELB and Route53. Also, the static pages are deployed in the S3 bucket. The Webservice and Website, both should be in the same domain.

When the user calls "www.domain.com/" it should be routed to the S3 server. However the API calls ([www.domain.com/api/**](http://www.domain.com/api/**)) should be routed to EC2 through ELB. Is there any way to
route API calls to ELB and website access calls to S3 using Route53?
or What is the best approach to resolve this?

Comment: So you have two domains? `www.domain.com` and `www.exmaple.com`?

Comment: @Marcin Sorry single domain.

Comment: You can't do this with R53 only. As @KaiBurjack pointed out, CloudFront should be considered instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can deploy both using the same domain name. APIs should be deployed using api.domain.com and websites can deploy using domain.com. For that, you need to purchase an SSL certificate with a domain name and subdomain (eg: https://example.com and https://api.example.com) support and do the following.

1. Configure certificate in AWS ACM
2. Deploy your website in the S3 bucket with CloudFront
3. Deploy APIs in EC2 with the support of a Load balancer (ELB)
4. Configure Route53 and define two routes. Ie, create Records with 'A record type' in Route53 with ELB address and  CloudFront address.
   See sample deployment architecture

[image]

Comment: How do i purchase an SSL certificate? i current have a domain and the ip address of my ec2 instance. my website is hosted with firebase hosting.

Comment: You can purchase an SSL certificate from AWS (ACM) or You can purchase a certificate from any SSL provider like DigiCert, Comodo, Godaddy and zerossl then configure it in the ACM of AWS.

Comment: Is it possible to have a quick discussion if your free?

Comment: I currently have nodejs backend host on an Ubuntu 20.04 server (EC2 instances). Everything was working with my ip address, but now i want to apply rerouting ie. instead of using the public ip address i would like to use api.website.com. How is that possible?

Comment: If you want to host a web service and website together in the same domain name, for example, domain.com and api.domainname.com, then you should purchase an SSL certificate with 'domain.com' and '*. domain.com'. Then you can define the routes in route53 (AWS) and configure certificate in ACM

Comment: On ACM, i requested my domain name and now the status is issued  what does that mean? do i still need to by the SSL?

Comment: Can you please clarify on the last point. How do i configure the certificate?

Comment: Yes the certificate was issued by AWS now you can configure the certificate at the AWS  ELB level or Node Server level or custom ELB like Nginx (if you placed Nginx placed in front of your Node server). Please check https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/easier-certificate-validation-using-dns-with-aws-certificate-manager/

Comment: I am using nginx as my reverse proxy

Comment: I have already completed this part.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251041/discussion-between-john-s-and-kd12345).